How to implement SSO using OKTA in PowerBuilder 2022 R3
We are running on the PB IDE Version 2022 Build 1900 and ours is a desktop application. I am confused on which security protocol to use to implement OKTA SSO.

Which security protocol should I use? - SAML, OIDC/OAUTH or LDAP. Which one involves the least efforts? (because this is an urgent request)
When going with SAML/OIDC/OAUTH we need a callback/redirect URL. How do I setup that with my desktop App?

How can I implement the SSO with my desktop PB App?

SAML is old (and is about as attractive as SOAP is today). OAuth2+OIDC is the current industry standard for all new projects. LDAP is not an SSO/authX scheme, it's a directory protocol - I think you meant to say Kerberos - but Kerberos does not work over the Internet, by-design, it only works in LAN environments.

"When going with SAML/OIDC/OAUTH we need a callback/redirect URL. How do I setup that with my desktop App?" - You'll register a custom URI scheme with the user's operating-system, e.g. such that all URIs using my-application:// as the URI-scheme (e.g. my-application://oidc-redirect or my-application://areas/settings (for example) will cause their desktop OS to start/open your .exe with the IDP's user/session/auth data passed in as command-line arguments. You'll then need to write your own code to pass that data to any existing running processes (e.g. using a named-pipe).

That said - rather than trying to shoehorn PowerBuilder into this, I think you should first plan your migration away from (and this is me being charitable) limited  and very slow-moving tooling like PowerBuilder - especially given its reputation for vendor lock-in - and once you're less-constrained then you'll be in a better position to implement SSO in your product.
